# Why isn't my submit button working on a magento CMS page?

Tags: php, forms, magento

all I'm having some issue with a custom form on a magento CMS page, the form is as follows:

```
<div class="comp-container">
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
<p class="comp-title">HOW TO ENTER</p>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<p>For your chance to win &pound;100 to spend on our website, enter your name and  email address below.If you win, you&rsquo;ll be notified by email &ndash; good luck!</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-md-6"><form id="competition" action="{{store url='/comp/checker.php'}}" method="post" name="competition"><span class="input-title">First Name:</span><input id="fname" class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" /> <br /> <span class="input-title">Last Name:</span> <input id="lname" class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" /><br /> <span class="input-title"> Email address: </span><input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" />**</form>**</div>
<div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<p class="comp-title">BOOST YOUR CHANCE OF WINNING!</p>
<p>Recommend a friend by entering their details as well and your name will be  entered into the draw twice. Want to recommend someone? <input id="comp-checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="comp-checkbox1" /></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 friend" style="padding-top: 20px;">
<p class="input-title" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;">Your Friends Email</p>
<div class="col-md-3"><input id="fr_name" class="form-control" type="text" name="fr_name" /></div>
<div class="col-md-3"><input id="fr_lname" class="form-control" type="text" name="fr_lname" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><input id="fr_email" class="form-control" type="email" name="fr_email" /></div>
&nbsp;
<p>Recommend another friend ? - <input id="comp-checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="comp-checkbox2" /></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 friend2" style="padding-top: 20px;">
<p class="input-title" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;">Your Friends Email</p>
<div class="col-md-3"><input id="fr_name2" class="form-control" type="text" name="fr_name2" /></div>
<div class="col-md-3"><input id="fr_lname2" class="form-control" type="text" name="fr_lname2" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><input id="fr_email2" class="form-control" type="email" name="fr_email2" /></div>
 &nbsp;
<p>Recommend another friend ? - <input id="comp-checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="comp-checkbox3" /></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 friend3" style="padding-top: 20px;">
<p class="input-title" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;">Your Friends   Email</p>
<div class="col-md-3"><input id="fr_name3" class="form-control" type="text" name="fr_name3" /></div>
<div class="col-md-3"><input id="fr_lname3" class="form-control" type="text" name="fr_lname3" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><input id="fr_email3" class="form-control" type="email"    name="fr_email3" /></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 20px;"><center><input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="submit" />**</form>**</center></div>
</div>
</div>
```

the idea is that the form sends the form values to ../comp/checker.php but when I save the page and hit the submit button it just sits there and doesn't go anywhere, I know that the magento cms editor removes certain things, but it hasn't removed anything from the form, any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento for security remove certain things like url. if you want to add url in CMS page then you have to use Magento code `{{store url=""}}` this code generate store url.

Example:

```
<form id="competition" action="{{store url='checker.php'}}" method="post" name="competition">
```

Magento also provide **custom variable** functionality so you can also use it.

Comment: that works a charm BUT for some reason magento is putting the </form> tag at the end of the div and not at the end where the submit button is, how do I stop this ?

Comment: Nevermind disabled the editor by default and my form works now, cheers anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try this html. I have removed duplicate entry **type="submit"** and corrected missing div tag.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<form id="competition" action="../comp/checker.php" method="post" name="competition">
<span class="input-title">First Name:</span><input id="fname" class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" /> <br /> 
<span class="input-title">Last Name:</span> <input id="lname" class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" /><br />
<span class="input-title"> Email address: </span><input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" />
<input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: just complete an incompleted div and removed duplicate of **type="submit"**

Comment: @jeroen Correct!. I will keep this thing in mind. Thanx